# Only show image if custom field exists

Tags: php, image, wordpress

How would I adjust this code to not show the image when there is no value for the custom field "imageembed"?

```
<?php $imageid = get_post_meta($post->ID, 'imageembed', true); ?>

   <div class="newsimage"><img src="<?php echo wp_get_attachment_url( $imageid ); ?>" width="640" /></div>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Something like this

```
<?php    
  if (strlen($imageid = get_post_meta($post->ID, 'imageembed', true))) {
?>
    <div class="newsimage"><img src="<?php echo wp_get_attachment_url((int) $imageid); ?>" width="640" /></div>
<?php } ?>
```